# Extracting a string with str.extract()

Tags: python, text-extraction

**string:** ["Kitchen & Dining >> Tableware & Cutlery >> Jug, Glass & Tray Sets"]

code:

```py
data['category_name'] = data_P['product_category_tree'].str.extract(r'([\w{3}\s]+?)(\s)+(\>>)', expand = True)
```

**output:**

```py
array([' Dining'], dtype=object)
```

Hello, I would like to extract the beginning of a character string up to '>>' but I can't because I don't see how to introduce '&' in my extraction. if someone can give me a clue?

Comment: That's not a string, but a list with a single string in it. However, it looks like you're using `pandas` (please add that to the tags and make it clear in your question). What you're trying to do is provide a pattern (effectively a regex with capturing groups) to `.extract` to get the first parts of the string before `>>` (probably not including the spaces before it either)? Your regex seems to be matching something else altogether. Why not simply use `r'(.*?)\s>>'`?

Comment: Or a slight adjustment `(.*?)(\s>>|$)` to also match the last item that isn't followed by `>>`

Comment: output : '["Kitchen & Dining'

Comment: thank you guys for your feedback, but I have the [" at the beginning of the character which is always present.

Comment: I solved my code, thanks a lot guys : r'(\w{3}.*?)(\s>>|$)'